# Jquery get Index() of appended li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing

I have a jquery `append()` to a `ul` function that I am trying to return the `index()` of the new `li`. After that I will have the ability to drag and drop the `li` into a different position and I need the index of that too.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you append then obviously the (one-based) index of the new element is `theNewElement.parentNode.childNodes.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you append use jquery lenght to get size of your list
http://api.jquery.com/length/

Substract 1 from length to get index of your appended li

Answer (score 1):

u can use `index` function in jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/N4SDw/

```
$('button').click(function(){
$('ul').append('<li>im list</li>');
 var list =  $('li:last').index();

    alert(list+1)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
$("<li>Test</li>").appendTo($("#test")).index();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3uqJT/